# CloudFront to Multiple API Gateway Mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have been stuck with this for some time so wanted to try my luck here. Here is my use case:

I have multiple API Gateways that are connected to my custom domain address. (say dev.api.example.com) each api gateway corresponds to a service that's mapped with a domain.
Example:

```
/users => Users API GW (12345abc.execute-api.com)
/notifications => Notifications API GW
/analytics => Analytics API GW and so on...
```

I need to set up a caching layer with CloudFront and have difficulty with wrapping my head around domain name, dns, api gateway, cloudfront combination. Here is what I have tried:

- Remove custom domain assignment from api gateway.
- create an alias record in Route53 that maps dev.api.example.com to cloudfront url.
  -Create one behaviour in the cloudfront distribution for each mapping as in the above examples and one origin for each AWS generated api gateway url that corresponds to a route (12345abc.execute-api.com).
- Assign these origins to corresponding behaviors so that /users routed to user api gw, /notification to notification gw and so on.
  The problem I had with this approach was, all requests had a /users added in the routing process by cloudfront. So if I sent the request to dev.api.example.com/:user-id, it would be routed as if I sent it as dev.api.example.com/users/id. I thought this might be related to origin path.
  Anyone knows how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write URL of cloudfront with Cloudfront functions.
AWS Cloudfront has 4 different type of functions.

- Viewer Request
- Viewer Response
- Origin Request
- Origin Response

[image: AWS-Cloudfront-functions]

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/

In your case, you can re-write url with functions on `Origin Request` request.
Simple function body will be like

```js
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, "/");
    return request;
}
```

This function will remove first part of url.
`/notifications/blabla` --> `/blabla`

`/users/:user-id` -> `/:user-id`